# Editing an existing AlarmClock instead of creating a new one

Tags: android, clock, alarm

Currently I'm using this method to create a new Alarm at a certain time:

```java
private void setAlarm(int hour, int minute) {
    Intent newAlarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    newAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
    newAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);
    newAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);

    startActivity(newAlarm);
}
```

The problem with this is that it creates a **new** alarm every time.
Is there a possibility to retrieve an existing alarm and editing that one?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. But if you use a alarmmanager with a pending intent you can still cancel it before it sets.